# Compile c++ console application with command-line arguments as static lib

Tags: c++

I'm trying to call the main function from a statically linked library.

```
 char *args[] = {
   "foo.exe", "--argument", NULL
 };
 staticLibMainFunction(sizeof args / sizeof args[0], args);
```

The function in the lib header is declared like

```
extern int staticLibMainFunction(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

But I get an Error => "unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl staticLibMainFunction(int,char * * const)"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to link your executable with this lib. The linkage process may depend on your compiler, but it's mainly done by passing `-Lpath/to/lib` -lYourLib` or `YourLib.a` to the compiler

Comment: It is linked with #pragma comment( lib, "libname.lib" )

Comment: @David 1) you should have shown/told us that. 2) that's a terrible way to do it - that info belongs in your build system, not in individual source files.